# Can't setup Filepond in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Getting this error while setup. Here is my setup in images.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM4iq.png)

[where i am using it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJN2C.png)

and called it like this  in the file above this line.

The code below this line is the code that is available in the official doc
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-filepond

FilePondDemo.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <file-pond
      name="test"
      ref="pond"
      label-idle="Drop files here..."
      v-bind:allow-multiple="true"
      accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
      server="/api"
      v-bind:files="myFiles"
      v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Import Vue FilePond
import vueFilePond from "vue-filepond";

// Import FilePond styles
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";

// Import FilePond plugins
// Please note that you need to install these plugins separately

// Import image preview plugin styles
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css";

// Import image preview and file type validation plugins
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";

// Create component
const FilePond = vueFilePond(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);

export default {
  name: "app",
  data: function () {
    return { myFiles: ["cat.jpeg"] };
  },
  methods: {
    handleFilePondInit: function () {
      console.log("FilePond has initialized");

      // FilePond instance methods are available on `this.$refs.pond`
    },
  },
  components: {
    FilePond,
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of writing `const FilePond = vueFilePond(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);` try `const FilePond = vueFilePond.default(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);`

Comment: NOT WORKING  
app.js:1534 Uncaught TypeError: vue_filepond__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.default is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/FilePondDemo.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1534:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20:30)
    at Module../resources/js/views/FilePondDemo.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:49240:203)
   at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20:30)
    at Module../resources/js/views/FilePondDemo.vue (app.js:49204:100)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20:30)

Comment: It's working on me. Maybe you should delete node_modules and install it again `npm i`

Comment: Have you checked my versions and all.

Comment: A bow down apologize sir. IT WORKED. Thank you.